# Паттерн MVC на java без фреймворков и сторонних каркасов

Tags: java, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования, dao

Скажите, а есть где-нить простое приложение написанное в учебных целях (не использующее фрейворки с готовым MVC-каркасом типа spring) и что бы в нем была нормальная здоровая реализация MVC, а не ТТУК. И при этом в моделе приложения был не один POJO класс, а 2 или 3 связанных между собой логически классов, и у каждого что бы был DAO и Service уровни. Хочется посмотреть на лучшие практики, но не на микроскопическом приложении на котором многих практик организации кода и организации взаимодействия кода просто не видно. На пример тот же телефонный справочник, но что бы не просто один POJO класс вида:

```
public class PhoneBook{
  private String name;
  private String phone;
}
```

и все на этом, а что бы было допустим так:

```
public class Group{
  private String name;
  List<People> peoples;
}

public class Phone{
  private String phone
}

public class Address{
  private String state;
  private String city;
  private String zipcode;
  private String street;
  private int house;
  private int apartment;
}

public class People{
  private String firstName;
  private String secondName;

  private List<Phone> phones;
  private List<Address> addreses;
}
```

Такой бы пример написанный без излишеств и без антипатернов был бы на много более наглядным и обучающим чем решение [этой задачи](https://javarush.ru/tasks/com.javarush.task.task36.task3608.big09). Хотя, да задача интересная, но оставляет много открытых вопросов. Я пробовал гуглить на гитхабе, но что-то ничего не нашел. Может я проглядел?

p.s.: и да, для этого примера, как мне кажется, что будет в DAO слое - не важно. Хоть фреймворки типа hibernate, хоть mock-ет

p.p.s.: хочется увидеть модель в несколько сущностей, объединенных между собой общим фасадом, обсервером, а так же все необходимые для работы модели слои в виде DAO и service, но при этом что бы в проекте были представление для чего-то отличного от web, и тонкие контроллеры без бизнеслогики (то есть что бы бизнеслогика была в моделе)

Comment: Я погугли не ного и нашел кучу примеров.

Comment: Ну создали классы и хорошо. Теперь базу, и свой crud и контроллер

Comment: Я думаю это должно помочь https://bit.ly/30gmguT . А вообще заходите на GitHub там в поиске вбиваете, что-то вроде: "MVC project" и он вам найдет пачку примеров по теме

Comment: Я так понимаю, что я не совсем четко написал требования к искомому проекту, и никто их не заметил, судя по комментариям. Давайте я продублирую, но списком: 1. Классическая реализация MVC паттерна, с использованием событийной модели (обсервер), и фасада для удобного взаимодействия с моделью 2. Написанная не джуниором как я, а человеком разбирающимся в предметной области. 3. Наличие НЕСКОЛЬКИХ СВЯЗАННЫХ а не одной сущности. 4 Использование самых тонких контроллеров которые возможны. 5. И гуглить я и сам догодался, и даже гуглил БЕЗ фреймворков (-spring -web), но результатов не получил.